# Every function works on my USB keyboard, except CTRL-LeftArrow (which I use constantly)

Tags: usb, keyboard

This is a new USB keyboard.  I did not install any of the software that comes with these things -- never have and would rather not unless all else fails.

Even CTRL-Shift-LeftArrow works but CTRL-LeftArrow just does nothing.  CTRL-RightArrow is fine.  Scroll Lock, Number Lock, and other keys also seem to function normally.

Anyone recommend some kind of key-stroke capture application to see how it's registering?

Comment: If it is brand new just take/send it back and ask for a replacement.

Comment: If you can, try it on another machine, if it still doesn't work then as ChrisF says take it back for replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on Windows,
run [CheckScanCode (Freeware, scroll down a bit to see the download link)](http://www.byremote.com.au/downloads/default.asp?SCLASS=UTILITIES) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to see if any keyboard scancode is received.

**My results for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>**

> KeyData: 21692417
>   Virtual Code: 37
>   Scan Code: 4915200
>   Text: ^{LEFT}
>   [_] ALT
>   [_] SHIFT
>   [X] CTRL